# Storing strings larger than 16 MB in MongoDB (MongoDB document size limit is 16 MB)

Tags: php, mongodb

## Goal:

I want to store large encrypted `strings` into `MongoDB`. As I've learned from the PHP driver documentation it's only possible to store data larger than 16 MB when I'm using `GridFS`. <s>The MongoDB PHP library doesn't offer a method to store "strings" in the grid. It just offers methods to store files (with a file path).</s> Correct me if I'm wrong. If there is any method/function from the `class` to store a `string` larger than 16 MB into the database, please tell me.

## EDIT/Answer:

### Storing strings larger than 16 MB to the MongoDB database

Ok, I finally figured it out and I'm glad it's working! There is a way to store `strings` with `GridFS` in the database. The documentation is not very easy to understand and I had to read the description of each `GridFS` `function` several times to understand what each `function` does and what I can achieve with each of them.

#### First step: Creating an instance of the MongoDB driver's Client class

```
function __construct(){
        $client = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://127.0.0.1/');
        $this->collection = $client->myExampleDatabase->myExampleCollection;
        $this->grid = $client->myExampleDatabase->selectGridFSBucket();
}
```

You **do not** have to use the `__construct` `function`!

#### So, to store a large string, you would have to do the following:

```
function insertDocument($id, $telegramuser, $message, $hash, $file) {
        try {   
                $stream = fopen("php://temp", "w+b");
                fwrite($stream, $file);
                rewind($stream);
                $fileid = $this->grid->uploadFromStream("cryptedObject", $stream, array("metadata" => array()));
                $document = array(
                    "id" => $id,
                    "telegram" => $telegramuser,
                    "fileid" => $fileid,
                    "encrypted" => $message,
                    "hash" => $hash,
                    "timestamp" => time(),
                );
                $this->collection->insertOne($document);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo "Error" . $e;
        }
}
```

I would recommend passing the `$fileid` variable from your `GridFSFile` object to a `document`, as in the function above. The important parts for storing `strings` are these:

```
$stream = fopen("php://temp", "w+b");
fwrite($stream, $file);
rewind($stream);
$fileid = $this->grid->uploadFromStream("cryptedObject", $stream, array("metadata" => array()));
```

`$fileid` contains the *automatically* assigned `id` of your `GridFSFile object` which you can use to pass into another `document` as a reference to your `GridFSFile object`.

#### When you use this function, you can retrieve the string from the database and you could echo or print it to the screen:

```
function getFile($id) {
        $document = $this->findDocument("id", $id);
        $fileid = $document->fileid;
        $stream = $this->grid->openDownloadStream($fileid);
        return stream_get_contents($stream);
}
```

First I retrieve the document from the database to get the `fileid` which is a `reference id` to my `GridFSFile object`. Then I use `openDownloadStream($fileid)` to create a `resource` in the `variable` `$stream` and with `stream_get_contents($stream)` I get the contents of the `resource` `$stream` which I can use for echoing or printing the  contents on the screen, or use it in any way I want.

That is the whole magic.

At the moment I cannot recommend the documentation of `MongoDB`, but to have a complete answer, you can find the `GridFS` PHP documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/class/MongoDBGridFSBucket/).

Comment: If you are claiming your driver does not support blobs with gridfs, add links to documentation where you think this is stated.

Comment: @D.SM check my updated post

Answer (score 1):

GridFS supports arbitrary data blobs. The database does not care (or know) whether the content being stored came from a file or from a network stream or from some other source or is a simple text string.