# Best way to store large string (nearly 1 mb) in MongoDB database

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backend

My application uses MongoDB, and I want to store big string files there. I was curious about the ideal way to store them. I'm attempting to setup Amazon S3 storage and insert the amazon-s3 url in MongoDB, but I'm not sure if that's efficient or not.

Answer (score 0):

1 MB is actually acceptable to put in a MongoDB record. The maximum size an individual document can be in MongoDB is 16MB with a nested depth of 100 levels.

You need embed the text as a value in a document of course. If you use JSON as input, you might need to escape some characters in the text.

```
{
   "_id": "...",
   "text": "................................",
   "other fields ....": "..."
}
```

For files larger than 16MB, there's GridFS: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/

See also [Storing strings larger than 16 MB in MongoDB (MongoDB document size limit is 16 MB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63042073/storing-strings-larger-than-16-mb-in-mongodb-mongodb-document-size-limit-is-16)

Comment: But I guess MongoDB provides 512mb of free storage, so I was thinking the other way..

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you were thinking the other way? Meaning that you would like to keep these large 1MB fields OUT of MongoDB so that it doesn't count against your free tier storage? Using S3 to store the actual object and then just saving the reference URL in MongoDB seems reasonable to me. There are just additional considerations when it comes to making sure the two systems stay in sync with each other, but that's the tradeoff for saving space.